# Ubuntu 80/tcpのポート開放が出来ない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu17.04のポート開放ができません。使っているものはUFWというポート開放ソフトです。
使用しているウェブサーバーは、Nginxです。

Shellにて以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
ufw enable
ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

なにが間違っているところなどはありますか？Cman等のサイトで外部からアクセスできるか試してみましたが応答が返ってきませんでした。

Comment: `ufw status`はどうなっていますか？ちなみに[UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)は（ポート開放ソフトと言うよりは）ファイアウォール(iptablesのフロントエンド)です。

Comment: コマンドの前にsudoは付けましたか？（もしくはrootのシェルで実行したか）